# Debug Assertion Failed in such simple example

Tags: c++, debugging, allocation

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Simple.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Simple s;
    s = Simple();
}
```

**Simple.cpp**

```
#include "Simple.h"

Simple::Simple(void)
{
    ptr = new int[10];
}


Simple::~Simple(void)
{
    delete [] ptr;
}
```

**Simple.h**

```
#pragma once
class Simple
{
public:
    Simple(void);
    ~Simple(void);

private:
    int* ptr;
};
```

When I run main.cpp, program stops and return an error:

> Microsoft Visual C++ Debug Library
>   Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: ...ts\Visual Studio 2010 C++\simple error\Debug\simple
>   error.exe File: f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgdel.cpp
>   Line: 52
>
> Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)
>
> For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure,
>   see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
>
> (Press Retry to debug the application)

Why it happens in such common example?

Comment: Take a look at the [rule of 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a copy constructor and assignment operator. At the moment, your line

```
s = Simple();
```

does the following:

- Creates a temporary `Simple`, allocating memory for its pointer to point to.
- Assigns it to `s`, which simply copies the pointer across from the temporary.
- Destroys the temporary again, deallocating the memory now pointed to by both the pointer in the temporary *and* the pointer in `s`.

At this point, the pointer in `s` points to deallocated memory. When `s` goes out of scope, the `Simple` destructor tries to deallocate the memory `s`'s pointer points to again, and undefined behaviour occurs (in your case, your program crashes).

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarying response.